# Help managing AsynTask threads

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app in android and I'm trying to retrieve some pictures from the internet using an `AsyncTask` thread.
The thing is that I'm retrieving this pictures in a `loop` so for each index I'm launching a new `AsyncTask` thread.Each thread returnes a picture(imageView).

And here is my problem:

The threads launched return the pictures asynchorounsly so when I'm trying to acces the List that stores these images I get `ArrayIndexOutofBounds`.

This is my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<friends.size();i++)
                    {
            getUserPic(friends.get(i).getId());
                    }
```

This is the `getUserPic` method:

```
  public void getUserPic(String userID){

        imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=small";
    new Task().execute(new String[] {imageURL});

    }
```

And here is the thread:

```
 private class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

        @Override
        public Bitmap doInBackground(String...arg0){


            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(arg0[0]);
            try{
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

        profilePicBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(content);


            }
           catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return profilePicBitmap;

        }
        @Override
           public void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
                arrayImageView.add(imageView);
            }
}
```

So what I wanna do is something like:

```
  List<ImageView> arrayImageView=new ArrayList<ImageView>();



    for(i....)

    {
 arrayImageView[i]=getUserPic(...);
     }

 public ImageView getUserPic(String userID){

            imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=small";
        new Task().execute(new String[] {imageURL});
return ImageView;

        }
```

I mean each `ImageView` return by the AsyncTask thread to be returned also by the `getUserPic` method.So would be more easily for me to keep track of them.

Question:How do I proceed so the pictured returned by `AsynTask` to be also the variable that `getUserPic()` returns.

I hope u get what I mean.Thx

Comment: the `onPostExecute` method runs on the main (UI) thread. You probably have to synchronize it yourself.

Comment: I'm sure that I have to do that.But I don't really know how:P

Comment: I'd go with `@Override
           public void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
synchronized(arrayImageView) {
                arrayImageView.add(imageView);}
            }`

Comment: Actually I did use a LazyAdapter to retrieve the picture from facebook.This one retrieves the pictures from facebook and stores them on the Sdcard and after that sets them to an adapter.If u need something like, I can give it to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm right you can do this..

```
 for(i....)

    {
 arrayImageView[i]=getUserPic(...);
     }

 public ImageView getUserPic(String userID){

            imageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+userID+"/picture?type=small";
        new Task().execute(new String[] {imageURL});
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Please Wait....");//**progressDialog** an instance variable

return ImageView;

        }
```

and in postExecute dismiss this dialog.. I suggest this because at this moment the UI thread will be blocked and u can make sure your `imageView` is initialised with some value in `postExecute()` and can be returned when dialog is dismissed and the UI thread resumes..